# Quotient manifold of a finite group action

Tags: group-actions, quotient-spaces, orientation, manifolds-with-boundary, root-systems

Let R be a (crystallographic) root system on an Euclidian space $(E,⟨−,−⟩)$ and
$$W:=gen\{σ_r∣r∈R\}=gen\{σ_r∣r∈R^+\}$$ its associated reflection group. Taking $$M=E-\cup_{r\in R^+} H_r,$$ where $H_r$ is the hyperplane associated to $\sigma_r$, $W$ acts freely on $M$ (which is a smooth manifold since it is an open subset) and therefore the orbit space $M/W$ is a smooth manifold. I would to know when $M/W$ is a compact and orientable manifold without boundary or at least an example for which this happends.

Answer (score 2):

This can never be true. The Weyl group acts freely on $M$ and an open fundamental domain is given by any Weyl chamber in the root system, which thus maps homeomorphically to the quotient. Unless I misunderstand your definition of root system this is a positive cone in euclidean space, taking a sequence of points going out to infinity along a ray shows that this space is never compact.

Comment: the definition that I have used is 1) span R=E 2) \sigma_r R \subseteq R for all r \in R. 3) If r, tr \in R with t real, then t=1 or t=-1. 4) for all r_1, r_2 \in R , 2(\langle r_1,r_2\rangle)/\langle r_1,r_1\rangle} is an integer

Comment: I have written the definition that I have used

Comment: Then you are using the standard definition, and my answer stands. an even cleaner argument for why the space can never be compact is that under these conditions the Weyl group is a finite group, and a finite cover of a compact space is always compact, but an unbounded subset of Euclidean space is not compact.

Comment: ok, you right. Do you know if it can be oriented??

Comment: It is isomorphic to an open subset of \R^n so it comes with an easy choice of orientation from the determinant on \R^n.

Comment: and what about the boundary??

Comment: It is without boundary. I gave an explicit description of the quotient you requested and all of these follow-up questions follow easily from that. You should sit down and try writing out what happens for A_n or D_n, all of this is clear from a few examples.